# How to create a diskimage of an SD card with partitions having different filesystems?

Tags: windows, windows-10, disk-image, ext4, fat32

I have a 16GB SD card with 10%FAT32 90%EXT4. I want to get a single disk image file that would contain all of the disc contents. How can I create a disk image of such a disc on Windows 10?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: You cannot create an ISO image (colloquially: CD/DVD image) from an SD card, for obvious reasons. Perhaps, you should ask about your actual aim.

Comment: @DanielB Are you sure about that?

Comment: @infamoustrey Yes. Though there is no difference in file structure (both are raw images), the term “ISO image” refers to an image of/for an optical disc. SD cards obviously aren’t optical media.

Comment: @DanielB Though the nomenclature might be correct, one could build an iso from any file structure could they not? Including that of an SD card?

Comment: @infamoustrey: Yes, if you see it like that, it's certainly possible. My impression was that the OP wanted a disk image (which he called ISO image) straight from the SD card. Unfortunately, no clarification was given.

Answer (score 5):

Linux dd.

```
dd if=/dev/sdX# of=/home/duckqueen/Desktop/usbimage.iso
```

Comment: The question asks specifically about Win 10, so you might want to add a sentence about doing this with a Live DVD session on a Win 10 machine (including mounting a persistent drive).

Comment: Given that the card has an ext partition, and the asker knows as much, it can be taken that he/she/it has at least a glancing knowledge of Superior OS'. I thought stating all that would be redundant, and if they were going to pursue my answer a 40 second search would put them right. I don't know how or why "persistence" comes into it.

Comment: It is unclear from the answer if `/dev/sdX#` means disk or partition... I mean if you'd wrote `/dev/sdX` it would be 100% that you meant disk, but why bother with additional `#`? From the context I think you meant disk...

Answer (score 1):

You could use a tool like [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/), it will read a usb to an iso and also write it back.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may find in the Control panel a tool "file history" there on the bottom left by "see also" go to "System Image Backup" and "create a system image" it should create an iso-file.

If you need a backup you could also use backup tools with gui for windows.

Or try the solution above with ImgBurn or CdBurnerXp.

E.g. Aomei [this](http://www.aomeisoftware.com/download/adb/BackupperFull.exe)  or  Paragon [this](http://dl.cdn.chip.de/downloads/5382012/br14_free_ger.exe?cid=54436355&platform=chip&1477939225-1477946725-318182-B-cb56620cafcdb0d67f8e29fcd58abc1e.exe) or Acronis.